# Umbraco Macro raise Null Reference error

Tags: .net, macros, umbraco

I've created a "PageNotFound" template. When it is invoked by its URL everything is fine. But when it is shown when user entered an invalid URL, inner macros is not loaded and in the source code of the page I received this error:

Error generating macroContent: 'System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at umbraco.library.RenderTemplate(Int32 PageId, Int32 TemplateId)'

Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this could be due to [a bug in the RenderTemplate method](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/xslt/4741-Query-String-Problems). Do you absolutely have to use RenderTemplate, or is there another way that you could solve what you're trying to do.

If you could describe what the RenderTemplate bit is supposed to do, an alternative can be recommended.

Comment: Hi <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/node [string(data [@alias='umbracoNaviHide']) != '1' and (string(data [@alias='component']) = '0' or string(data [@alias='component']) = '1')]">
    <xsl:sort select="@sortOrder" order="ascending" data-type="number" />
      <xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:RenderTemplate(@id, @template)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

Comment: This is the way that I used, RenderTemplate. As I said it works when I called it by browsing the page-not-found page. But, when I entered invalid URL, the macro could not executed properly in page-not-found page

Comment: But what are you rendering? Which template, what is in it and do you really need to render the template or could you do it in the XSLT as well?

Comment: I found the issue! It is a bug in umbraco that you can find it in issue list of umbraco! I wrote a simple code to render the template and now it is solved

Comment: I do believe I pointed that bug out in my answer. Would be good if you shared the code so other people would be able to benefit as well.